# how to configure the effect reconciler to pass errors to rollback with redux-offline?

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-persist, redux-offline

**Problem**

I have just recently found out about this library and was implementing it for a react native app, but can't get my head around how the effect reconciler passes the errors to rollback. I am firing the below action, and whether the response is success or failure, the effect reconciler directly passes everything to commit. can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

```js
const saveProfileRequest = (query, link): Action => ({
  type: SAVE_PROFILE_PICTURE_REQUEST,
  meta: {
    offline: {
      effect: {
        url: BASE_URL,
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
          query,
          variables: { url: link }
        })
      },
      commit: { type: SAVE_PROFILE_PICTURE_SUCCESS, meta: { link } },
      rollback: { type: SAVE_PROFILE_PICTURE_FAILURE }
    }
  }
});
```

**Expectations**

As I am currently implementing the offline capabilities to an existing app, I was expecting the effect reconciler to pass success response to commit and pass error response to rollback.

**Store config**

```js
    // @flow
    import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from 'redux';
    import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
    import { offline } from '@redux-offline/redux-offline';
    import offlineConfig from '@redux-offline/redux-offline/lib/defaults';
    import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
    import autoMergeLevel2 from 'redux-persist/lib/stateReconciler/autoMergeLevel2';
    import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
    import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
    import type { Store } from '@types/Store';
    import rootReducer from '@reducers/index';
    
    const persistConfig = {
      key: 'root',
      storage: AsyncStorage,
      whitelist: ['reducerOne', 'reducerTwo', 'reducerThree'],
      stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2
    };
    
    const persistedReducer = persistReducer(
      persistConfig,
      combineReducers(rootReducer)
    );
    
    const store: Store = createStore(
      persistedReducer,
      composeWithDevTools(
        applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware),
        offline({
          ...offlineConfig,
          retry(_action, retries) {
            return (retries + 1) * 1000;
          },
          returnPromises: true
        })
      )
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue, because our GraphQL API always return 200, but with an error object, so I needed to customize it.

Basically you need to customize the **discard** function, returning **false** in case of an error.

The default discard already return **false** in case of Network issue, but if you have errors inside your response, and it's returning 200 instead, you can customize.

Documentation for Discard: https://github.com/redux-offline/redux-offline/blob/develop/docs/api/config.md#discard

Default implementation (you can use that as initial draft): https://github.com/redux-offline/redux-offline/blob/develop/src/defaults/discard.js